# Gradle Report Plugin Task is not executed properly

Tags: gradle, groovy, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am trying to execute  Plugin task depending on the build task of the root project.
Therefore I've already did this in my gradle.build:

```
task dependencyCheck(dependsOn: dependencyUpdates){*Task instructions*}

build.dependsOn(dependencyCheck)
```

The dependencyUpdates task creates a report of all dependencies that are stored in an external folder.
The console says that the task is executed successfully:
[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wugZ4.png)

But actually it is not refreshing the report.xml in the external folder and the modification date stays the same.

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:
I had to set the outputDir.
I thought the default path would be applied to the task like when executing it manually, but that is not the case.